# iPhone system font

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, typeface

What is the name of the default system font on the iPhone?

I would like to retrieve this for customizing a `UIView`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

> To the delight of font purists
> everywhere, the iPhone system
> interface uses Helvetica or a variant
> thereof.
>
> The original iPhone, iPhone 3G and
> iPhone 3GS system interface uses
> Helvetica. As first noted by the
> always excellent DaringFireball, the
> iPhone 4 uses a subtly revised font
> called "Helvetica Neue."
> DaringFireball also notes that this
> change is related to the iPhone 4
> display rather than the iOS 4
> operating system and older iPhone
> models running iOS 4 still use
> Helvetica as the system font.
>
> iPod models released prior to the
> iPhone use either Chicago, Espy Sans,
> or Myriad and use Helvetica after the
> release of the iPhone.

From http://www.everyipod.com/iphone-faq/iphone-who-designed-iphone-font-used-iphone-ringtones.html

For **iOS9** it has changed to **San Francisco**. See http://developer.apple.com/fonts for more info.

Comment: Currently it is Helvetica Neue Regular font.

Comment: For iOS9 it has changed to San Fransisco.
See https://developer.apple.com/fonts/ for more info.

Answer (score 104):

If you're doing programatic customisation, don't hard code the system font. Use `UIFont systemFontOfSize:`, `UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:` and `UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize` ([Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/systemFontOfSize:)).

This has become especially relevant since iOS 7, which changed the system font to Helvetica Neue.

This has become *super* especially relevant since iOS 9, which changed the system font *again* to San Francisco.

Comment: I'm not going to change the system font, that's a bad idea. But I want it for some html in UIWebView.

Comment: This doesn't change the system font - it just gives you `UIFont` instances of the system font using the given sizes, and will always return the system fonts regardless of future iOS updates.

Comment: The font I'm seeing in my UIWebView doesn't looking like Helvetica to me. I might be wrong but setting the font for my view takes away my doubt.

Comment: "don't hard code the system font" is good advice, or really bad advice, depending on the situation. Personally, I wish I had hardcoded `Helvetica`... doing that now.

Comment: Totally agree, don't hardcode, please.
This should be the right answer to this question

Answer (score 16):

afaik iPhone uses "**Helvetica**" by default 
< iOS 10

Comment: as seen by other answers, it depends on iOS version

Answer (score 15):

## Swift

**Specific font**

Setting a specific font in Swift is done like this:

```
let myFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)
```

If you don't know the name, you can get a list of the available font names like this:

```
print(UIFont.familyNames())
```

Or an even more detailed list like this:

```
for familyName in UIFont.familyNames() {
    print(UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName))
}
```

But the system font changes from version to version of iOS. So it would be better to get the system font dynamically.

**System font**

```
let myFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
```

But we have the size hard-coded in. What if the user's eyes are bad and they want to make the font larger? Of course, you could make a setting in your app for the user to change the font size, but this would be annoying if the user had to do this separately for every single app on their phone. It would be easier to just make one change in the general settings...

**Dynamic font**

```
let myFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
```

Ah, now we have the system font at the user's chosen size for the [Text Style](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIFontTextStyleHeadline) we are working with. This is the recommended way of setting the font. See [Supporting Dynamic Type](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/supporting-dynamic-type.html) for more info on this.

## Related

- [Visual List of iOS Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34557032/3681880)
- [How do I make an attributed string using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/3681880)

Answer (score 12):

You can always use

```
UIFont *systemFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
NSLog(@"what is it? %@ %@", systemFont.familyName, systemFont.fontName);
```

The answer is:

**Up to iOS 6**

```
 Helvetica Helvetica
```

**iOS 7**

```
.Helvetica Neue Interface .HelveticaNeueInterface-M3
```

but you can just use `Helvetica Neue`

Comment: in Swift on iOS 9 I get `.SFUIText-Regular` as `systemFont.familyName`

Comment: @simpleBob More on that: http://designforhackers.com/blog/apples-new-san-francisco-font/

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure there is an api to get the default system font name. So I just get the name like this :

```
    //get system default font
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];        
    fontname = label.font.fontName;
    [label release];
```

Looks stupid but it works.

Comment: UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12.0]; <!-- gets default font

Comment: There are easier methods.. But +1 for thinking out of the box

Comment: It looks better :P `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];` See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some update for supporting *iOS 7*. It has [`Dynamic Font Size`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIFont/fontDescriptor) now.

> For any and all apps that support “Dynamic Type,” users can select a
>   font size in iOS 7 that works system wide, simply by visiting the
>   "General" section under "Settings" and selecting "Font Size."

```
UIFont *dynamicFont  = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
```

And constants list, *detailed explanation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Text_Styles)*

```
NSString *const UIFontTextStyleHeadline;
NSString *const UIFontTextStyleSubheadline;
NSString *const UIFontTextStyleBody;
NSString *const UIFontTextStyleFootnote;
NSString *const UIFontTextStyleCaption1;
NSString *const UIFontTextStyleCaption2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Category **UIFontSystemFonts** for **UIFont** (*UIInterface.h*) provides several convenient predefined sizes.

```
@interface UIFont (UIFontSystemFonts)
 + (CGFloat)labelFontSize;
 + (CGFloat)buttonFontSize;
 + (CGFloat)smallSystemFontSize;
 + (CGFloat)systemFontSize;
@end
```

I use it for chat messages (labels) and it work well when I need to get size of text blocks.

```
 [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

```
UIFont *systemFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
```

This will give you the system font with the default system font size applied for the label texts by default.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

You should always use the system defaults and not hard coding the font name because the default font could be changed by Apple at any time.

There are a couple of system default fonts(normal, **bold**, *italic*) with different sizes(label, button, others):

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
let font2 = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
let font3 = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
```

beaware that the default font size depends on the target view (label, button, others)

Examples:

```
let labelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.labelFontSize)
let buttonFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.buttonFontSize)
let textFieldFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. download required .ttf file
2. add the .ttf file under copy bundle resource, double check whether
   the  ttf file is added under resource
3. In info.pllist add the ttf file name as it is.
4. now open the font book add the .ttf file in the font book, select
   information icon there you find the postscript name.
5. now give the postscript name in the place of font name

Answer (score 0):

The default font for iOS is San Francisco . You can refer the [link](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) for further details