# Visual List of iOS Fonts?

Tags: ios, uifont, typeface

I am looking for a list of iOS Fonts for iOS 7.  I have found the list on Apple's developer site, I am just wondering if anyone knows of a visual list where each font name is typed out in its typeface.  I have seen one or two before, but the latest one I have seen was for iOS 5, and much more has been added since then.

Comment: Seriously, thanks for the down votes.  Please don't bother to leave a comment for why you vote this question down when it is an honest question that an answer could provide help to others on.  If you want to down vote it, fine, but do as this site suggests and leave a reason.

Comment: See https://github.com/akosma/fontbrowser

Comment: I didn't downvote but your question shows little effort on your part. Some simple Google searches would have pointed you to several existing resources and apps that allow you to view iOS fonts.

Comment: My simple google search just led me here, and I got a good answer, so I'm upvoting.

Comment: http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/samples-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/ seems to work.

Comment: Why is a Stack Overflow question pointing to iOS fonts seen as somehow more valuable than iOS fonts itself?

Comment: I find that SO is familiar, reliable, clearly organized and allows me to get the answer I need faster than just about anything else out there. Google also seems to place SO answers at the top, so other people must feel the same way.

Comment: @ rmaddy not to mention Stack Overlfow is the definition of "a simple Google search". The question belongs here even if it can be found somewhere else with more effort.

Comment: I google "all fonts preview in iOS", and this one is on the top of list. So I would up vote, though the list only update to iOS 9, and now it is iOS 14.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Have you tried [iOS Fonts](http://iosfonts.com)?

This gives you a visual of all of the available fonts with the ability to enter your own string of text to see how it would look.

This doesn't appear to have been updated for iOS 7 however but I am unaware of any additional fonts which have been added since iOS 6.

Comment: FYI, only seems to work for me with an actual iOS device. Chrome and Firefox didn't display the fonts.

Comment: In case anyone reaching this answer and is still frustrated because he has a windows machine, there is an answer for you down below - there is a website that provides images and not text http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/samples-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 50):

This font list was made with Xcode 7 and iOS 9.

[image]

If you are setting one of these programmatically and need the font name, you can do the following:

```
print(UIFont.familyNames)
// ["Copperplate", "Heiti SC", "Iowan Old Style", "Kohinoor Telugu", "Thonburi", "Heiti TC", "Courier New", "Gill Sans", "Apple SD Gothic Neo", "Marker Felt", "Avenir Next Condensed", "Tamil Sangam MN", "Helvetica Neue", "Gurmukhi MN", "Times New Roman", "Georgia", "Apple Color Emoji", "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Kailasa", "Kohinoor Devanagari", "Kohinoor Bangla", "Chalkboard SE", "Sinhala Sangam MN", "PingFang TC", "Gujarati Sangam MN", "Damascus", "Noteworthy", "Geeza Pro", "Avenir", "Academy Engraved LET", "Mishafi", "Futura", "Farah", "Kannada Sangam MN", "Arial Hebrew", "Arial", "Party LET", "Chalkduster", "Hoefler Text", "Optima", "Palatino", "Lao Sangam MN", "Malayalam Sangam MN", "Al Nile", "Bradley Hand", "PingFang HK", "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Courier", "Cochin", "Hiragino Mincho ProN", "Devanagari Sangam MN", "Oriya Sangam MN", "Snell Roundhand", "Zapf Dingbats", "Bodoni 72", "Verdana", "American Typewriter", "Avenir Next", "Baskerville", "Khmer Sangam MN", "Didot", "Savoye LET", "Bodoni Ornaments", "Symbol", "Menlo", "Bodoni 72 Smallcaps", "Papyrus", "Hiragino Sans", "PingFang SC", "Euphemia UCAS", "Telugu Sangam MN", "Bangla Sangam MN", "Zapfino", "Bodoni 72 Oldstyle"]
```

And if you need the name of a particular bold/italic/etc style, you can get it like this:

```
for familyName in UIFont.familyNames {
    print(UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName))
}
```

Answer (score 24):

(Original answer in ObjC) You can get a list at run-time:

```
// available fonts listed in xcode output
for (id familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", familyName);
    for (id fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) NSLog(@"  %@", fontName);
}
```

(Added: Swift one liner):

```
UIFont.familyNames.forEach{ print($0); UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: $0).forEach{ print("  ", $0) } }
```

This will spit out:

```
Thonburi
  Thonburi-Bold
  Thonburi
  Thonburi-Light
Snell Roundhand
  SnellRoundhand-Black
  SnellRoundhand-Bold
  SnellRoundhand
  ...
```

I have also made a small app that can be used to browse through all the available fonts. Check it out [here](https://github.com/marchv/FontViewer).

Comment: How do you filter out any custom-added ones that are included in your app's Info.plist?

Comment: For anyone thinking they can just loop such code (like I just did!) to try to set the font along with the name, this will not work as the info.plist needs each font included to be able to render :(

Answer (score 6):

Here's a visual list of [fonts in iOS 7](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2013/09/fonts-in-ios-7/).

Comment: @autremoi Thanks - it works for me in Safari and Chrome, but I'm not sure how to fix it for Firefox.

Comment: Neither this site nor iosfonts.com work for me. All showing same basic font. Tried Chrome, FF, IE, and Edge on Windows 10. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of such a tool, but there's a workaround.

1. You can list the standard fonts in Xcode. Create a xib (or storyboard), add a label and change its font. There you can see the list of all fonts.
2. On your OSX computer, you have a "Font Book" application, where you can view each font.

Also remember that you are not limited to the system fonts if you're building an application. You can provide yours as well.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [iOS Font List](http://iosfontlist.com/). It's new and has a few more features then some of the other sites. It also includes downloadable fonts which none of the other sites even mention.

Answer (score 2):

Swift implementation:

```
// Available fonts (console output)
for familyName in UIFont.familyNames() {
    print(familyName)
    for fontName in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName) {
        print(fontName)
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.