# Are there any new fonts available for iOS 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, ios8

Possible duplicate: [Visual List of iOS Fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125129/visual-list-of-ios-fonts)

Have there been any font additions for iOS 8?

EDIT: Check out this site, as per mentioned below
http://iosfontlist.com/#availability=8.0&preinstalled

Comment: No! There is not a new fonts in it. But it is now simpler to generate a new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the new fonts introduced in iOS 8.0:

```
Apple SD Gothic Neo Ultra Light
Damascus Light    
Khmer Sangam MN
Khmer Sangam MN
Kohinoor Devanagari
Kohinoor Devanagari Light
Kohinoor Devanagari Book
Kohinoor Devanagari Medium
Lao Sangam MN
Lao Sangam MN
```

**UPDATE:** Added missing `Damascus Light`. For the font name to use in code, see **cnotethegr8**'s answer.

Comment: is it true that you can generate a new font in ios 8?

Comment: @HomelessPeopleCanCode what do you mean by "generate new"? Do you mean, using fonts downloaded by you then manually adding them to your project, or do you mean, let the code download the fonts automatically for you? Or do you mean, you draw new fonts created by you?

Comment: I mean using fonts downloaded by you then manually adding them to your project. I bought a new font recently and it would be nice if I could include it !

Comment: @HomelessPeopleCanCode sure, check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006772/custom-font-not-working-programetically-in-swift/28843547#28843547

Comment: You missed, Damascus Light

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is! Checkout http://iosfontlist.com/ This site is much more accurate then the previously mentioned site.

Here's the list of new iOS8 fonts with their `UIFont fontWithName:` string.

```
AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight
DamascusLight
KhmerSangamMN
KohinoorDevanagari-Light
KohinoorDevanagari-Book
KohinoorDevanagari-Medium
LaoSangamMN
```

Note: for anyone going to this font list site, clicking on the font reveals the `fontWithName:` version. Some of them are not so obvious such as the font `Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN W3` has a font name of `HiraKakuProN-W3`.