# custom font not working programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I've followed the step to to add custom fonts in xcode at [swift day-by-day](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/07/23/ios8-day-by-day-day-4-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder) and
[custom fonts](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/#doublechecktarget) but I'm not able to set that font in app label programmatically.

```
var labeladd = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40, 50, 70, 22))
    //  label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
 ///  labeladd.font=UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)
   labeladd.font = UIFont(name:"Source Sans Pro",size:15)
    labeladd.textColor=UIColor.blackColor()
    labeladd.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    labeladd.text = "this is custom fonts"
    myview.addSubview(labeladd)
```

Comment: please help me i cant find where i am wrong or mistaking

Comment: Did you add your Custom font into info.plist file?

Comment: Off topic: how did you add color to your sample code?

Answer (score 174):

Let's say you want to add this font: `SourceSansPro-Regular.otf`

Four steps:

1. Add the font file `SourceSansPro-Regular.otf` to your project, make sure you select your target in the "Add to targets".

[image]

Go to the target's **Build Phases** and make sure it is under **Copy Bundle Resources**. If not, add it.

[image]

2. Go to the target's **Info**. Add a new entry **Font provided by application** then add a new item with this value `SourceSansPro-Regular.otf`.

[image]

3. From your finder, double click on the file `SourceSansPro-Regular.otf`, it might ask you to install the font to your Font Book.

4. Open the OS X **Font Book** application, navigate to your font then press **Command+i**. Note the **PostScript name** and use that name in your Swift code. In this case, it's `SourceSansPro-Regular`.
   [image]

So in your code:

`labeladd.font = UIFont(name:"SourceSansPro-Regular", size:15)`

Comment: I can't find the font in my font book application :( I am trying to add Philosopher-Regular.ttf

Comment: From your finder, double click on Philosopher-Regular.ttf, it might ask you to install the font to your Font Book.

Comment: I was not adding .ttf into info.plist. very minor mistake.

Answer (score 22):

I've found (XCode 12) that unless your font happens to be **already used in your Main.storyboard**, that even if you have done all the correct steps of registering the font file in your app, copied to your bundle resources, used the PostScript name, yadda, yadda, that it still didnt show up and trying to use it in UIFont(name: size:) would still return nil. :-(

I worked around this current bug (?) by manually registering *all* my custom fonts at startup in AppDelegate application(_ application:  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

```
let fonts = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "ttf", subdirectory: nil)
fonts?.forEach({ url in
    CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(url as CFURL, .process, nil)
})
```

(adapted from [Xcode: Using custom fonts inside Dynamic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507905))

Comment: Wow, what a weird bug

Comment: Weird bug. Thanks for the fix. Btw this works for .otf fonts too if you change the extension appropriately.

Comment: so weird, thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes the name of the font is not the name of your file. I was trying to use the NexaBook.otf font with the name "NexaBook" and at the end the problem was that the right name of the font is "Nexa-Book". 
To check you are using the right name write this code in the viewDidLoad and check the name of the font:

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames
    {
        print(family)
        for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
        {
            print("== \(names)")
        }
    }
```

In my case I got:

```
...
Nexa
== Nexa-Book
Avenir Next
== AvenirNext-Medium
== AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic
== AvenirNext-DemiBold
...
```

I get this idea from [Common Mistakes With Adding Custom Fonts to Your iOS App](https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) where you can find a great description of the problems working with custom fonts.

Comment: Good way for debuging font names, I was missing "W03" in CirceRoundedW03-Regular.

Comment: Every steps are right , but I can't find the font family in the Logged list. not found in storyboard, can't set programatically

Answer (score 8):

[image]
(1)First select the "Font" folder then make sure it's selected.

Comment: Yes., adding the target to the font is fixed my issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you are getting the font in storyboard but not in font family and are not able to set it progammatically, then the reason is that the Xcode might not have compiled the font. To solve it:

1. Set the required font(say: Roboto Bold) as the font of any UI element on storyboard E.g UILabel.
2. Run the project
3. Now check the font family names. The required font(say: Roboto Bold) name would have appeared in it.
4. Now you can set the required font(say: Roboto Bold) progammatically :)

Comment: Step 1 solved my Problem. I tried everything else. Do you know why?

Comment: Still not clear why this is needed in 2020, but it does work in loading the fonts correctly.

Comment: copied to bundle->checked the target->checked info.plist->checked copy bundle resources-> still the Font family is not able find in the Log. Nobody Is commenting on what if did not find the Font in Logged list.

Comment: @Anees were you not able to get the font in font family, as per the given steps as well?

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the issue quite a long time. It turned out that I forgot to add a `.ttf` / `.otf` extension to the font name in Info.plist.

Comment: .otf and .ttc was my case and it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Follow Apple Guide to:

[**Adding a Custom Font to Your App**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app)

Beyond this, I've found that if your font is not already present in a Storyboard item, UIFont.familyNames.sorted() won't list it.

**The workaround is to make a storyboard, you can leave unused, and add there a UILabel for each custom font you want to be available programmatically, and then set your font as custom font from properties panel.**

This is not clean solution, but I didn't find any other solution.

Best regards.

/GM

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a custom font within a framework, you need to manually load the font in app delegate before using it.

[Xcode: Using custom fonts inside Dynamic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507905/xcode-using-custom-fonts-inside-dynamic-framework)