# CKEditor: "Math-tex" and "font-family:Kruti (Hindi Font)" not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fonts, xcode8

I have created a website using CKEditor. I want to integrate CKEditor font family "Math-tex" and "font-family:Kruti" in iOS but I am not able to do so.

Please assist.

Comment: Please go through the link : -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006772/custom-font-not-working-programetically-in-swift

Comment: Thanks for your assistance but My Question is Ckeditor math font not working in iOS.
here is the example, which I got from the server

 <p><span class=\"math-tex\">\\(x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}\\)</span></p>

and I want to show this Maths Equation in iOS.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvfxc.png).