# How to set heading, subheading, body, footnote, and captions font for dynamic type text styles in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic-typing, textkit, text-styling

I was working through the [Using Text Kit to Manage Text in Your iOS Apps](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-text-kit-ios-programming-guide/) tutorial. It was written for Objective C but I thought I would try to do it anyway using Swift.

However, when I got to the following code I couldn't figure out how to set the heading and other styles for the `UITextView` using Swift. Here is the Objective C code:

```
- (IBAction)applyHeadlineStyle:(id)sender {
    [_textView setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]];
}

- (IBAction)applySubHeadlineStyle:(id)sender {
    [_textView setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline]];
}

- (IBAction)applyBodyStyle:(id)sender {
    [_textView setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]];
}

- (IBAction)applyFootnoteStyle:(id)sender {
    [_textView setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote]];
}

- (IBAction)applyCaption1Style:(id)sender {
    [_textView setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption1]];
}

- (IBAction)applyCaption2Style:(id)sender {
    [_textView setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption2]];
}
```

I tried

```
textView.setFont =
textView.preferredFontForTextStyle =
```

Neither of these seemed to work, though, and I couldn't find any Swift answers on SO.

Comment: Xcode auto completes it for you.  Start writing it and then press escape. Give it a try.

Comment: My problem was that `setFont` and `preferredFontForTextStyle` are not methods or properties of `UITextView` so there was nothing to autocomplete. I was just guessing. I did find a solution on another website though.

Comment: You will notice a lot of methods just don't have the word set as it is not necessary try it always without "set"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77092/text-kit-tutorial-swift) had some code samples that showed how to do it.

```
// headline
textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.headline)

// subheadline
textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.subheadline)

// body
textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)

// footnote
textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.footnote)

// caption 1
textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.caption1)

// caption 2
textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.caption2)
```

## See also

- [Setting the font programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34826120/3681880)

Comment: how can i undo set style