# Which Android font is the closest to iOS default System Font?

Tags: android, ios

I want to use the same font in my Android app, which I use in my iOS app.

In my  iOS app I only use the system font with.

```
textField.font = UIFont.systemfontOfSize(12)
```

**Which Android font is the closest to iOS default System Font?**

Comment: Helvetica font family. Though I think this question is not fit for SO, as it asks us to recommend and not solve a problem.

Comment: What does "Android font" mean? Beyond that, which "iOS default System Font" interests you? I don't even *use* iOS, and in 10 seconds' of searching, I can find that there are [several "iOS default System Font" variants, depending on iOS version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3838662/115145). What does "the closest" mean?

Comment: ^ Upvote for not using iOS!

Comment: Helvetica is the system font for iOS6 and iOS7..closest means to use Helvetica family

Comment: helvetica font is for default font of iOS , and for using it in your android application you can simply download the font and by using this [library](https://github.com/soroushjavdan/CustomFontWidgets) make your custom font views .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. You probably shouldn't be doing whatever you're trying to do..

But, it's worth noting that you can package a font within your apk. In other words, it doesn't matter if androids fonts don't cut it for you, you can just put IOS's font into your app (I am not a lawyer).

Put it in your recourses and use it with something like:

```
Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/font1.ttf");

TextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```